# Usar função dentro do response success do ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma lista de tarefas com checkboxes, que quando marcado atualiza, via ajax, o status da tarefa no banco de dados, o que quero fazer é retornar o percentual de conclusão da lista, que já está feito no backend, e também já possui uma função js chamada "porcentagem", o problema é que no success da marcação do checkbox eu gostaria de pegar o valor da função porcentagem, porém não há retorno.

Ex:

```
function porcentagem(id) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        method:'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.success == 1) {
                return data.porcentagem;
            }
        }

    });
}
```

**success:** ajax do checkbox:

```
                if(data.success == 1) {
                    var id = $("input[name='id']").val();
                    alert( porcentagem(id) );
                }
```

A função porcentagem foi definida antes do ajax, e mesmo assim o console me mostra:

> Uncaught TypeError: porcentagem is not a function

Comment: Tentou pegar o retorno do Ajax em uma variável e exibir depois disso a variável em si ?

Comment: mas nesse caso a variável da função porcentagem não seria local?